# How to make a specific string work in a try-except block?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, valueerror, try-except

I don't want to make the user be able to enter anything other than numbers as the input for the "number" variable, except for the string "done".

Is it possible to somehow make an exception to the rules of the try-except block, and make the user be able to write "done" to break the while loop, while still keeping the current functionality? Or should I just try something different to make that work?

```
while number != "done":
    try:
        number = float(input("Enter a number: ")) #The user should be able to write "done" here as well
    except ValueError:
        print("not a number!")
        continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the error message contains `'done'`:

```py
while True:
    try:
        number = float(input("Enter a number: "))
    except ValueError as e:
        if "'done'" in str(e):
            break
        print("not a number!")
        continue
```

also in this case `continue` is not necessary here (for this example at least) so it can be removed

Answer (score 1):

Separate the two parts : ask the user and verify if it is `done`, then parse it in a `try/except`

```
number = None
while True:
    number = input("Enter a number: ") 
    if number == "done":
        break

    try:
        number = float(number)
    except ValueError:
        print("not a number!")
        continue

    print("Nice number", number)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to make exceptions to the rules, you can instead do something like,

```
while True:
    try:
        number=input("Enter a number: ")
        number=float(number)
    except:
        if number=="done":
            break
        else:
            print("Not a number")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe convert the number to float afterwards. You can check if number is not equal to done,then convert the number to float

```
number = 0
while number != "done":
    try:
        number = input("Enter a number: ") #The user should be able to write "done" here as well
        
        if number=="done":
            continue 
        else: 
            number = float(number )
    except ValueError:
        print("not a number!")
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
while True:
    try:
        user_input = input("Enter a number: ")
        if user_input == "done":
            break
        number = float(user_input)
    except ValueError:
        print("not a number!")
        continue
```

You can cast the input to float after checking if the input is 'done'

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to approach this situation.
First one that came across my mind is by doing:

```
while True:
    user_input = input("Enter a number: ")
    if user_input == "done":
        break
    else:
        try:
            number = float(user_input)
        except ValueError:
           print("not a number!")
           continue
```